# Class vs ID with nested CSS

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

Suppose a HTML like this:

```
<div id="header">
  <span class="title">Title</span>
  <!-- more spans and other things here -->
</div>
```

This would work together with a nested CSS:

```
#header .title { /* CSS */ }
```

This works of course, but I don't like the usage of `class` here. As I need the style `title` only once, I would like to use an id. But then the name would have to be something like `header_title` (since I might have other titles in the HTML), resulting in a CSS

```
#header #header_title { /* CSS */ }
```

Now this seems to defeat the purpose of nested CSS, then I could just drop the first `#header` completely.

I can't really figure out a way to do this "right". Am I missing something, or do I just have to live with some "dirty" code here?

Comment: Could you not just use something like `#header > span { /* CSS */ }` ?

Comment: I actually have other spans in there, just left then out for clarity.

Comment: For multiple spans nested in the header div you could always incorporate the nth child selector? But I don't see what's wrong with just using either of your examples? Why do you wish to not use them so much? Sorry for the questioning, I'm just curious :)

Comment: Well, it's more or less academic, it's just that none of the examples really "feels" right from a design point of view ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually doesn't really matter.

What matters about your markup is that it's *readable*; HTML is about being *semantic*, so that your markup represents your content. By doing so, if you come back to your HTML a few months later without touching it, you should be able to quickly pick up on what on earth you wrote :)

Semantically, `#header .title` makes a lot more sense to me over `#header #header_title`, for two reasons; one, since it's easier to read, and two, since the purpose of ids is, well, to identify! You could use `#header_title` by itself, but it's much cleaner to limit the amount of ids you have.

Answer (score 2):

Using `#id .class {style:rules;}`  is not "dirty".  It is the correct way of doing it.  Also, if you "might have other titles in the HTML", it would be even more correct to use classes rather than have 15 id based rules.

Answer (score 0):

How about using header tags

```
#title h1{/* CSS */}

<div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

I guess that's what the tags are there for :)

Comment: See my comment above. It's actually not a single span in there, but many, including other elements. I just stripped it down for simplicity, maybe I went a bit too far ;)

Comment: Did you mean to type #header instead of #title?

Comment: @lucasclemente I wouldn't include the name of the parent itself, to keep it readable it is unnecessary, I guess if its an ID you want to use (because it will only be used once) I would use a prefix to keep it simpler? #header #hTitle ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an ID if there is only one element you want to style since IDs cannot be duplicated.  If there is a possibility that there could be multiple elements with the class `title` (both in and outside of the `#header` div), then stick with your first CSS example as this will ensure that only elements with the title class that are inside of the #header element will be styled.

It really depends on what the rest of your HTML looks like and what you are trying to style.

Comment: I need the class `title` only once, but have different "titles" that are styled differently.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're more worried about naming convention.

It's totally okay to just use

```
 #header #title {/** css **/}
```

In your case the best method is probably to use the "dirty" method.

I'm not sure why you would choose to use span over h1, h2 because I would just do

```
 #header h1 {/** css **/}
```

since you most likely will only have one h1 tag within your #header